# Display date once and display results under the respective date. [MySQL/PHP]

Tags: php

```
$query_ListAbsence = "SELECT count(dated) as dtd, classed, name FROM att group by dtd, classed by dtd desc";
        $la = mysql_query($query_la, $sshost) or die(mysql_error());
        $row_la = mysql_fetch_assoc($la);


do{

....

 }while ($row_la = mysql_fetch_assoc($la));
```

I want to result to show as

```
--date--
name1 - classed1
name2 - classed2


--another date---
namea - classeda
nameb - classedb
```

and so on...

But when inside the do{}while loop the date is displayed the number of times the loop runs.  Can i display the results as shown with a single table.  This is done by MySQL / PHP.

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($la)) {
$arr[$row['your_date']][] = $row;

}
```

And than loop through $arr array;

Comment: Within the do{} while loop?